# Recognizing a non-word sound on android

Tags: android, voice-recognition

## Background:

I started working out at the gym.

Currently, I'm working only on triceps.

I determine to myself some sets that I have to do every time I'm at the gym.

As you might know, the fitness appliance that works on triceps look like some iron rods connected to weights that I have to lift up.

So, I thought that I'll log it in my Android phone,

So I'll really know what I did and what I didn't.

So, I would have to create an `.Xml` file which record what I really did. But if I'll put the number manually, I'll lose all the point, So...

## Question:

I need, somehow, to recognize the weights-unhand sound. When I unhand from the rod, the weight falling and making some sound (I guess you know the sound, like a small Boom).

Is there any way to recognize it?

Comment: Something like a voice recognizing algorithm?

Comment: @Balavishnu What do you mean by your question? That was mine ..

Comment: Have you done something?

Comment: visit this http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect the algorithm here, anyway I can help you get started.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982760/algorithm-for-song-recognition)

You can start by recording your "small boom" sound. You can run FFT on these clips and extract the magnitude of the same. You can store this value as a hash and compare it with the live sound.

for additional details check [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6855/FFT-of-waveIn-audio-signals), [here](http://www.devoxx.com/display/DV11/What+Shazam+doesn%27t+want+you+to+know) and [here](http://www.redcode.nl/blog/2010/06/creating-shazam-in-java/)

Comment: I thought there is some API for this .. I didn't expect for algorithm